# Check DistanceWidget's marker dragend

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

**DistanceWidget:**

```
function DistanceWidget(map,markers) {
    this.set('map', map);
    this.set('position', map.getCenter());
    this.set('markers',markers);
    // MARKER CENTER
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        draggable: true,
        icon: {
            url: "/public/img/move.png",
            size: new google.maps.Size(20, 20),
            anchor: new google.maps.Point(10, 10)
        },
        title: 'Di chuyển'
    });
    marker.bindTo('map', this);
    marker.bindTo('position', this);
    var me = this;
    var radiusWidget = new RadiusWidget(markers);
    this.bindTo('circle', radiusWidget);
    radiusWidget.bindTo('map', this);
    radiusWidget.bindTo('markers', this);
    radiusWidget.bindTo('center', this, 'position');
    this.bindTo('distance', radiusWidget);
    this.bindTo('bounds', radiusWidget);
    this.bindTo('radius', radiusWidget);
}
```

**RadiusWidget:**

```
RadiusWidget.prototype.center_changed = function() {
    var bounds = this.get('bounds');
    if (bounds) {
        var lng = bounds.getNorthEast().lng();
        var position = new google.maps.LatLng(this.get('center').lat(), lng);
        this.set('sizer_position', position);
    }
};

RadiusWidget.prototype.checkCenterDragend = function(){
    //TODO SOMETHING HERE
}
```

I move (drag) MARKER CENTER in DistanceWidget, center_changed prototype will update. That's great.

**Question:** How can I check event dragend of MARKER CENTER to update something in checkCenterDragend prototype.

**Thank for your time.**

Comment: `google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'dragend',function() {});` doesn't work? (inside `function DistanceWidget`)

Comment: google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'dragend',function() {}); it's working in DistanceWidget. But I want to do code in checkCenterDragend prototype

Answer (score 0):

Simply call the method in the `dragend`-handler:

place this after the line var `radiusWidget = new RadiusWidget(markers);`

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function() {
  radiusWidget.checkCenterDragend.call(radiusWidget,this.getPosition());
});
```

The first argument passed to the function will be the marker-position(the center)